# Chess application with GUI and AI in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, mvc, swing, chess

I've included the files that I felt were relevant (i.e I haven't included the individual pieces in the inheritance hierarchy). I'm particularly curious as to whether the system as a whole is constructed well. I've used MVC along with the Observer pattern to decouple the model and view.

Controller.java

```
package chess;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class Controller implements Observer {
    private Board board;
    private final View view;
    private final MinimaxAI ai;
    private Position startOfPlayerMove;
    private Position endOfPlayerMove;
    private Team currentTeam;

    public Controller() {
        board = new Board();

        view = new View();
        setupBoardImages();
        view.addObserver(this);

        ai = new MinimaxAI(4, Team.WHITE);
    }

    // Main control method for entire program
    public void run() {
        currentTeam = Team.WHITE;
        Move move;
        GameStatus status;
        boolean running = true;

        while (running) {
            // Check if there's a checkmate or stalemate. If there is, end of game
            status = board.getGameStatus(currentTeam);
            if (status == GameStatus.CHECKMATE || status == GameStatus.STALEMATE) {
                view.gameOverMessage(status, currentTeam);
                running = false;
                continue;
            }

            move = getMove();

            // Check if move follows the rules of Chess. If not, repeat turn
            if (!board.isValidMove(move, currentTeam)) {
                view.invalidMoveMessage(move);
                continue;
            }

            // Attempt to make move. If move results in the mover being checked, repeat turn
            if (!board.makeMove(move)) {
                view.checkMessage(currentTeam);
                continue;
            }

            // Update GUI and switch to next player
            updateView(move);
            view.moveMessage(move);
            currentTeam = getNextTurn();
        }
    }

    // Maps pieces on the board to the view
    private void setupBoardImages() {
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++) {
                Position position = new Position(row, column);
                if (board.pieceAt(position) != null)
                    view.updateTile(position, board.pieceAt(position).toString());
                else
                    view.clearTile(position);
            }
        }
    }

    private Move getMove() {
        if (currentTeam == Team.WHITE)
            return ai.pickMove(board);
        else
            return pickPlayerMove();
    }

    private Move pickPlayerMove() {
        while (startOfPlayerMove == null || endOfPlayerMove == null)
            waitForValidInput();

        Move ret = new Move(startOfPlayerMove, endOfPlayerMove);
        resetMove();

        return ret;
    }

    private void waitForValidInput() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Team getNextTurn() {
        return Team.otherTeam(currentTeam);
    }

    // Update GUI with new state of board resulting from a move
    private void updateView(Move move) {
        String updateNewPiecePos = board.pieceAt(move.destination()).toString();

        view.clearTile(move.start());
        view.updateTile(move.destination(), updateNewPiecePos);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable gui, Object information) {
        switch (view.getUpdateType()) {

        case SAVE:
            save(information);
            break;
        case LOAD:
            load(information);
            break;
        case MOVE:
            updatePlayerMove(information);
            break;
        default:
            throw new AssertionError("Enum doesn't seem to match with any supported types");
        }
    }

    private void updatePlayerMove(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof Position))
            throw new AssertionError("There doesn't seem to be a position here");

        Position position = (Position) object;

        if (isValidEndOfMove(position))
            endOfPlayerMove = position;
        else {
            startOfPlayerMove = position;
            endOfPlayerMove = null;
        }
    }

    private boolean isValidEndOfMove(Position position) {
        Piece selectedPiece = board.pieceAt(position);

        return (selectedPiece == null || selectedPiece.getTeam() != currentTeam) && startOfPlayerMove != null;
    }

    private void save(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof File))
            throw new AssertionError("There doesn't seem to be a file here");

        File file = (File) object;

        try (FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream)) {

            os.writeObject(board);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            view.fileIOError();
        }
    }

    private void resetMove() {
        startOfPlayerMove = null;
        endOfPlayerMove = null;
    }

    private void load(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof File))
            throw new AssertionError("There doesn't seem to be a file here");

        File file = (File) object;

        try (FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(fileStream)) {

            board = (Board) os.readObject();
            resetMove();
            setupBoardImages();

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            view.fileIOError();
        }
    }
}
```

Board.java

```
package chess;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Board implements Serializable {
    private final Piece[][] board;

    // Cache is used to save moves in case you want to reverse them.
    private final Stack<Piece> deletedPieceCache;
    private final Stack<Move> moveCache;
    private final Stack<Position> pawnToQueenConversionCache;

    // Maps a pieces string representation onto it's relative value
    private final Map<String, Integer> heuristicMap;

    public Board() {
        board = new Piece[8][8];
        deletedPieceCache = new Stack<>();
        moveCache = new Stack<>();
        pawnToQueenConversionCache = new Stack<>();
        heuristicMap = new HashMap<>();

        buildHeuristicMapping();
        addPieces(0, 1, Team.WHITE);
        addPieces(7, 6, Team.BLACK);
    }

    public void reverseLastMove() {
        Move move = moveCache.pop();
        Position start = move.start();
        Position end = move.destination();

        board[start.row()][start.column()] = pieceAt(end);
        board[end.row()][end.column()] = deletedPieceCache.pop();

        checkForReversePawnReplacement();
    }

    // Returns true if last move was successful, false if unsuccessful
    public boolean makeMove(Move move) {
        Position start = move.start();
        Position end = move.destination();
        Team team = pieceAt(start).getTeam();

        cacheMove(move, end);
        movePiece(start, end);
        checkForPawnReplacement(start, end);

        if (isChecked(team)) {
            reverseLastMove();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void movePiece(Position start, Position end) {
        board[end.row()][end.column()] = pieceAt(start);
        board[start.row()][start.column()] = null;
    }

    private void cacheMove(Move move, Position end) {
        deletedPieceCache.push(pieceAt(end));
        moveCache.push(move);
    }

    public GameStatus getGameStatus(Team team) {
        for (Move move : generatePossibleMovesForTeam(team)) {
            if (makeMove(move)) {
                reverseLastMove();
                return GameStatus.INPLAY;
            }
        }

        // No moves can be made, game is either in checkmate or stalemate
        if (isChecked(team))
            return GameStatus.CHECKMATE;
        else
            return GameStatus.STALEMATE;
    }

    // Returns true if a move doesn't break the rules
    public boolean isValidMove(Move move, Team team) {
        if (pieceAt(move.start()) == null)
            return false;

        if (pieceAt(move.start()).getTeam() != team)
            return false;

        List<Move> possibleMoves = generatePossibleMovesForPiece(move.start());
        return possibleMoves.contains(move);
    }

    public List<Move> generatePossibleMovesForTeam(Team team) {
        List<Move> ret = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Position pos : getPositionsOfPiecesForTeam(team))
            ret.addAll(generatePossibleMovesForPiece(pos));

        return ret;
    }

    // Adds piece objects to board for each team
    private void addPieces(int backRow, int frontRow, Team team) {
        board[backRow][0] = new Rook(team);
        board[backRow][7] = new Rook(team);
        board[backRow][1] = new Knight(team);
        board[backRow][6] = new Knight(team);
        board[backRow][2] = new Bishop(team);
        board[backRow][5] = new Bishop(team);
        board[backRow][3] = new Queen(team);
        board[backRow][4] = new King(team);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            board[frontRow][i] = new Pawn(team);
    }

    private boolean isChecked(Team team) {
        Position kingsPosition = getKingPosition(team);
        Team otherTeam = Team.otherTeam(team);

        for (Position position : getPositionsOfPiecesForTeam(otherTeam)) {
            Move move = new Move(position, kingsPosition);
            if (isValidMove(move, otherTeam))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // If pawn reached the end, replace with queen
    private void checkForPawnReplacement(Position start, Position end) {
        if (pieceAt(end) instanceof Pawn && (end.row() == 0 || end.row() == 7)) {
            replacePawnWithQueen(end);
            pawnToQueenConversionCache.push(start);
        } else
            pawnToQueenConversionCache.push(null);
    }

    private void replacePawnWithQueen(Position end) {
        board[end.row()][end.column()] = new Queen(pieceAt(end).getTeam());
    }

    // Uses cache to reverse a move where a pawn has turned into a queen
    private void checkForReversePawnReplacement() {
        Position pos = pawnToQueenConversionCache.pop();
        if (pos != null)
            board[pos.row()][pos.column()] = new Pawn(pieceAt(pos).getTeam());
    }

    private List<Move> generatePossibleMovesForPiece(Position start) {
        Piece piece = pieceAt(start);

        if (piece instanceof Pawn)
            updatePawnSurroundings(start);

        return removeInvalidMoves(piece.generateMoveList(start));
    }

    // Tells a pawn object where its surrounding pieces are so it can make a move
    private void updatePawnSurroundings(Position pawnPosition) {
        boolean leftTake = false, rightTake = false;
        boolean isPieceInFront = false, isPieceTwoInFront = false;

        Pawn pawn = (Pawn) pieceAt(pawnPosition);
        int directionModifier = getDirectionModifier(pawn.getTeam());
        Position pos;

        // True if an opposing teams piece is at top left of pawn
        pos = new Position(pawnPosition.row() + directionModifier, pawnPosition.column() + 1);
        if (pieceAt(pos) != null && pieceAt(pos).getTeam() != pawn.getTeam())
            rightTake = true;

        // True if an opposing teams piece is at top right of pawn
        pos = new Position(pawnPosition.row() + directionModifier, pawnPosition.column() - 1);
        if (pieceAt(pos) != null && pieceAt(pos).getTeam() != pawn.getTeam())
            leftTake = true;

        // True if a piece is in front of the pawn
        pos = new Position(pawnPosition.row() + directionModifier, pawnPosition.column());
        if (pieceAt(pos) != null)
            isPieceInFront = true;

        // True if no piece lies 2 spots ahead of pawn
        pos = new Position(pawnPosition.row() + (directionModifier * 2), pawnPosition.column());
        if (pieceAt(pos) != null)
            isPieceTwoInFront = true;

        pawn.setSurroundingPositions(leftTake, rightTake, isPieceInFront, isPieceTwoInFront);
    }

    // Returns the direction where a pawn should move given the team it's in
    private int getDirectionModifier(Team team) {
        if (team == Team.WHITE)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    // Filters out any moves that don't follow the rules of the game
    private List<Move> removeInvalidMoves(List<Move> moves) {
        List<Move> ret = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Move move : moves)
            if (isClearPath(move) && isValidDestination(move))
                ret.add(move);

        return ret;
    }

    // Returns true if no other pieces lie in a pieces path when moving
    private boolean isClearPath(Move move) {
        List<Position> path = move.drawPath();

        for (Position position : path)
            if (pieceAt(position) != null)
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    private Position getKingPosition(Team team) {
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++) {
                Position pos = new Position(row, column);
                if (pieceAt(pos) != null && (pieceAt(pos) instanceof King) && pieceAt(pos).getTeam() == team)
                    return pos;
            }
        }

        throw new AssertionError("King not found");
    }

    // Returns List of all positions of a given teams pieces that can make a move
    private List<Position> getPositionsOfPiecesForTeam(Team team) {
        List<Position> ret = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                Position pos = new Position(i, j);
                if (pieceAt(pos) != null && pieceAt(pos).getTeam() == team)
                    if (generatePossibleMovesForPiece(pos).size() > 0)
                        ret.add(pos);
            }

        return ret;
    }

    // Returns true if the destination isn't occupied by a pieces own team
    private boolean isValidDestination(Move move) {
        Position start = move.start();
        Position end = move.destination();
        Team team = pieceAt(start).getTeam();

        if (pieceAt(end) != null && pieceAt(end).getTeam() == team)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public Piece pieceAt(Position position) {
        if (!position.isOnBoard())
            return null;

        return board[position.row()][position.column()];
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void printBoard() {
        for (Piece[] row : board) {
            System.out.println();
            for (Piece piece : row)
                if (piece == null)
                    System.out.print("-");
                else
                    System.out.print(piece);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        deletedPieceCache.clear();
        moveCache.clear();
        pawnToQueenConversionCache.clear();
    }

    private void buildHeuristicMapping() {
        heuristicMap.put("k", 950);
        heuristicMap.put("q", 100);
        heuristicMap.put("r", 60);
        heuristicMap.put("b", 40);
        heuristicMap.put("n", 30);
        heuristicMap.put("p", 10);
    }

    public int generateHeuristicValue(Team team) {
        int value = 0;

        for (Piece[] row : board)
            for (Piece piece : row)
                if (piece != null) {
                    if (team == piece.getTeam())
                        value += heuristicMap.get(piece.toString().toLowerCase());
                    else
                        value -= heuristicMap.get(piece.toString().toLowerCase());
                }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Piece.java

```
package chess;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

abstract public class Piece implements Serializable { 
    private final Team team;
    
    public Piece(Team t) {
        team = t;
    }
    
    protected void addPositionToMoveList(List<Move> moves, Position start, Position pos) {
        if (pos.isOnBoard())
            moves.add(new Move(start, pos));            
    }
    
    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }
    
    // Generates set of all possible positions a piece can move to
    public abstract List<Move> generateMoveList(Position start);
}
```

View.java

```
package chess;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Observable;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class View extends Observable {
    // Allows us to access a tile given a position on the board
    private final JButton[][] tiles;

    // Main frame that the GUI runs on
    private final JFrame frame;

    // Main panel that all tiles on the board are placed on
    private final JPanel board;

    // Panel that holds any buttons the player needs
    private final JPanel playerOptions;

    // Maps string representation of a piece to its image
    private final Map<String, Image> pieceToImage;

    // Displays any information on the game (i.e checks, illegal moves)
    private final JTextField gameStatus;

    // These components represent the filemenu dropdown menu for saving and loading
    private final JMenuBar fileMenuBar;
    private final JMenu fileMenu;
    private final JMenuItem save;
    private final JMenuItem load;

    // Allows view to tell the controller any requests that come from the player
    private UpdateType updateType;

    public View() {
        frame = new JFrame("Chess");
        board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 8));

        fileMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        load = new JMenuItem("Load");
        setUpFileMenu();

        playerOptions = new JPanel();
        setupPlayerOptions();

        gameStatus = new JTextField("");
        gameStatus.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        tiles = new JButton[8][8];
        setupBoardButtons();
        addBoardBehaviour();

        pieceToImage = new HashMap<>();
        addPieceImagesToMap();

        addComponentsToFrame();
        configureFrame();
    }

    private void configureFrame() {
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setUpFileMenu() {
        fileMenu.add(save);
        fileMenu.add(load);
        fileMenuBar.add(fileMenu);

        addSaveBehaviour();
        addLoadBehaviour();
    }

    // Tells program what to do when save button is pressed
    private void addSaveBehaviour() {
        save.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            File file = getFileFromUser();

            if (file != null) {
                updateType = UpdateType.SAVE;
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(file);
                updateType = UpdateType.NONE;
            }
        });
    }

    // Tells program what to do when load button is pressed
    private void addLoadBehaviour() {
        load.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            File file = getFileFromUser();

            if (file != null) {
                updateType = UpdateType.LOAD;
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(file);
                updateType = UpdateType.NONE;
            }
        });
    }

    public void fileIOError() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error when loading in file");
    }

    // Allows user to select a file from their computer's file menu
    private File getFileFromUser() {
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());

        if (jfc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            return jfc.getSelectedFile();

        return null;
    }

    public UpdateType getUpdateType() {
        return updateType;
    }

    public void gameOverMessage(GameStatus status, Team team) {
        if (status == GameStatus.STALEMATE)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game has ended in a stalemate");
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Checkmate, " + Team.toString(Team.otherTeam(team)) + " has won");
    }

    // Updates the images displayed on the board for a move
    public void updateTile(Position position, String update) {
        tiles[position.row()][position.column()].setIcon(new ImageIcon(pieceToImage.get(update)));
    }

    // Remove image from a tile
    public void clearTile(Position position) {
        tiles[position.row()][position.column()].setIcon(null);
    }

    public void invalidMoveMessage(Move move) {
        gameStatus.setText("Attempted move " + move + " is invalid");
    }

    public void moveMessage(Move move) {
        gameStatus.setText(move.toString());
    }

    public void checkMessage(Team team) {
        gameStatus.setText(Team.toString(team) + " would be checked as the result of that move");
    }

    private void addComponentsToFrame() {
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, board);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, playerOptions);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, gameStatus);
    }

    private void setupPlayerOptions() {
        playerOptions.add(fileMenuBar);
    }

    // Adds the actionlistener to every button in the board
    private void addBoardBehaviour() {
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
            for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++)
                addButtonBehaviour(row, column);
    }

    // Allows user to select pieces for a move
    private void addButtonBehaviour(final int row, final int column) {
        tiles[row][column].addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            updateType = UpdateType.MOVE;
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(new Position(row, column));
            updateType = UpdateType.NONE;
        });
    }

    // Create buttons and add to panel
    private void setupBoardButtons() {
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++) {
                JButton button = new JButton();
                setBackgroundForTile(row, column, button);
                tiles[row][column] = button;
                board.add(button);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setBackgroundForTile(int row, int column, JButton button) {
        if ((column % 2 == 0 && row % 2 == 0) || (column % 2 == 1 && row % 2 == 1))
            button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        else
            button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    private void addPieceImagesToMap() {
        Image[][] pieceImages = new Image[2][6];
        readPieceImages(pieceImages);

        pieceToImage.put("q", pieceImages[0][0]);
        pieceToImage.put("k", pieceImages[0][1]);
        pieceToImage.put("r", pieceImages[0][2]);
        pieceToImage.put("n", pieceImages[0][3]);
        pieceToImage.put("b", pieceImages[0][4]);
        pieceToImage.put("p", pieceImages[0][5]);

        pieceToImage.put("Q", pieceImages[1][0]);
        pieceToImage.put("K", pieceImages[1][1]);
        pieceToImage.put("R", pieceImages[1][2]);
        pieceToImage.put("N", pieceImages[1][3]);
        pieceToImage.put("B", pieceImages[1][4]);
        pieceToImage.put("P", pieceImages[1][5]);
    }

    // Get piece images from file
    private void readPieceImages(Image[][] pieceImages) {
        int imageSize = 64;

        try {
            BufferedImage imageBuffer = ImageIO.read(new File("piece_images.png"));
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                    pieceImages[i][j] = imageBuffer.getSubimage(j * imageSize, i * imageSize, imageSize, imageSize);

        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println("Error with handling images");
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Move.java

```
package chess;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Move implements Serializable {
    private final Position start;
    private final Position end;

    public Move(Position s, Position e) {
        start = s;
        end = e;    
    }

    // Example: drawPath((1, 1), (4, 4)) returns [(2, 2), (3, 3)]
    public List<Position> drawPath() {
        List<Position> path = new ArrayList<>();
        MovementType movementType = getMovementType();
        
        // Not necessary for horse, return empty list
        if (movementType == MovementType.HORSE)
            return path;

        int rowIncrement = getIncrementValues(movementType)[0] * getRowDirection();
        int columnIncrement = getIncrementValues(movementType)[1] * getColumnDirection();

        int rowOffset = rowIncrement;
        int columnOffset = columnIncrement;

        // Draw path until we reach end position
        while (start.row() + rowOffset != end.row() || start.column() + columnOffset != end.column()) {
            path.add(new Position(start.row() + rowOffset, start.column() + columnOffset));

            rowOffset += rowIncrement;
            columnOffset += columnIncrement;
        }

        return path;
    }

    // Returns 1 if piece moved down, -1 if moved up, 0 if piece didn't change row
    private int getRowDirection() {
        if (end.row() - start.row() > 0)
            return 1;
        else if (end.row() - start.row() < 0)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    // Returns 1 if piece moved right, -1 if moved left, 0 if piece didn't change column
    private int getColumnDirection() {
        if (end.column() - start.column() > 0)
            return 1;
        else if (end.column() - start.column() < 0)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public Position destination() {
        return end;
    }

    public Position start() {
        return start;
    }

    private MovementType getMovementType() {
        if (Math.abs(start.row() - end.row()) == Math.abs(start.column() - end.column()))
            return MovementType.DIAGONAL;
        if (start.row() == end.row())
            return MovementType.HORIZONTAL;
        if (start.column() == end.column())
            return MovementType.VERTICAL;

        return MovementType.HORSE;
    }

    // Returns the change in co-ordinates that came from a movement
    private int[] getIncrementValues(MovementType movement) {
        int rowIncrement = 0;
        int columnIncrement = 0;

        switch (movement) {

        case DIAGONAL:
            rowIncrement = 1;
            columnIncrement = 1;
            break;
        case HORIZONTAL:
            columnIncrement = 1;
            break;
        case VERTICAL:
            rowIncrement = 1;
            break;
        default:
            throw new AssertionError("Enum doesn't seem to match with any supported types");
        }

        return new int[] { rowIncrement, columnIncrement };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Move))
            return false;

        Move move = (Move) obj;

        return start.equals(move.start) && end.equals(move.end);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return start.hashCode() * 27832 + end.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return start.toString() + " to " + end.toString();
    }

    enum MovementType {
        DIAGONAL, HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL, HORSE
    }
}
```

Minimax.java

```
package chess;

/*
 * Uses the minimax algorithm with alpha beta pruning to make moves
 */
public class MinimaxAI {
    private final int maxDepth;
    private final Team team;

    public MinimaxAI(int m, Team t) {
        maxDepth = m;
        team = t;
    }

    // Return move that minimax algorithm wants to make by
    // running minimax on all possible moves
    public Move pickMove(Board board) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int current;
        Move optimalMove = null;

        for (Move move : board.generatePossibleMovesForTeam(team)) {
            if (board.makeMove(move)) {
                current = min(board, 1, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                if (current >= max) {
                    optimalMove = move;
                    max = current;
                }

                board.reverseLastMove();
            }
        }
        
        board.clearCache();
        return optimalMove;
    }

    // For all moves the opposing team could make, return least optimal for the AI
    private int min(Board board, int depth, int alpha, int beta) {
        if (depth == maxDepth)
            return board.generateHeuristicValue(team);

        for (Move move : board.generatePossibleMovesForTeam(Team.otherTeam(team))) {
            if (board.makeMove(move)) {
                beta = Math.min(max(board, depth + 1, alpha, beta), beta);
                board.reverseLastMove();
            }
            
            if (alpha >= beta)
                break;
        }

        return beta;
    }

    // For all moves the AI could make, return most optimal
    private int max(Board board, int depth, int alpha, int beta) {
        if (depth == maxDepth)
            return board.generateHeuristicValue(team);

        for (Move move : board.generatePossibleMovesForTeam(team)) {
            if (board.makeMove(move)) {
                alpha = Math.max(min(board, depth + 1, alpha, beta), alpha);
                board.reverseLastMove();
            }

            if (alpha >= beta)
                break;
        }

        return alpha;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On first glance, I wouldn't call things just `View`, `Controller`, and `Observable`, even if they are indirectly qualified by their package. It's a bit surprising to see that in Java, the names suggest reusability and independence of Chess. It probably should be `ChessBoardView` and `ChessBoardController`. Having `Observable` as an interface is a bit unusual in Java MVC, it's more common to have the counter-part *Observer* and name it `Listener`, in this case `ChessBoardListener`.

The `fileStream` is overly qualified as `FileInputStream`, `InputStream` would suffice.

If `readPieceImages()` fails, the program will continue with broken data and throw a `NullPointerException` when calling `updateTile()` at `new ImageIcon(pieceToImage.get(update))`: `pieceToImage.get(update)` will return `null`, and `new ImageIcon((java.awt.Image) null)` throws a `NullPointerException` in the constructor.

Method `fileIOError()` could use `JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE` to signal to the user that the message is about an error.

Nice: Mostly immutable fields. You could go one step further and use unmodifiable collections as well. Instead of, in the constructor,

```
        pieceToImage = new HashMap<>();
        addPieceImagesToMap();
```

you could have

```
    private final Map<String, Image> pieceToImage = loadPieceImages();
```

and `loadPieceImages()` would create a `new HashMap<>()` plus `return Collections.unmodifiableMap(pieceToImage)`.

Besides, `pieceToImage` should probably cache the `ImageIcon`, not the `Image`. That would save repetitive constructor calls of `new ImageIcon` in `updateTile()`.

For `equals()` and `hashCode()` you might want to use Lombok, it saves a lot of boilerplate.

The `switch (movement)` could be avoided altogether by giving the `enum MovementType` fields `rowIncrement` and `columnIncrement`. This could also replace the `int[]` return type, which is not necessarily intuitive (one has to remember whether row or column comes first). (In other words. the implementation of the enum is not OO.)

The `MovementType` enum is also partially confusing, because in some contexts all four enum constants, including `HORSE` are allowed, and in some contexts, only 3 excluding `HORSE` are allowed.

Some of the methods and classes appear a bit long at first glance, and some responsibility misplaced. Loading and saving a board should probably not be in the same `Controller` as other UI functions.

Update: The current class `Board` conflates different responsibilities (it would change for more than one reason), and thus should be split:

- The `Board` itself, merely representing the chess board with the positions of the pieces. It shouldn't even know that the pieces are chess. Hypothetically, this should be reusable for implementing Draughts instead of Chess.
- An interface `Rules` which merely connects the Board and the AI to what's allowed.
- A class `ChessRules` which implements `Rules` for the actual rules of Chess.
- A class `ChessAI` or something like that for all parts currently in `Board` which only serve the purpose of feeding the `MinimaxAI`.
- The current behavior of the `MinimaxAI` is great, the behavior already doesn't know anything about Chess. The dependency could be decoupled so that even structurally it doesn't know about Chess. (Right now, `Board` is still specific to Chess.)

Update 2

- In enum `Team` (not shown in the question), method `otherTeam()` should not be a `static` utility method but an instance method of the enum.
- In enum `Team` (not shown in the question), method `toString()` also should not be a `static` utility method but an instance method of that enum.

Overall, I really enjoyed looking at the code. That's it for now, I might have a more detailed look later.